# WebSphere Liberty Server not starting up on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, redis, websphere, websphere-liberty

My Liberty Server was working fine a couple of days back but now I am getting some errors and the server is in "Started" state but the application is in "Stopped" state. When I checked the error logs, I could see that the application was not able to connect to Redis.

Some additional details about the environment:

1. Cisco VPN
2. IBM Cloud
3. Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0)
4. MacOS Monterey 12.4
5. Custom DNS set to (8.8.8.8) and Search domain is (ibm.com)
6. Redis is running on IBM Cloud
7. Redisson Java client for connecting to Redis

StackTrace of the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:932)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.offerTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:351)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:344)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:834)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute0(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:825)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:815)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:841)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:499)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:96)
    at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture.setSuccess0(DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java:200)
    at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture.access$400(DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java:41)
    at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture$1.operationComplete(DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java:75)
    at io.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroupFuture$1.operationComplete(DefaultChannelGroupFuture.java:48)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$CloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:1164)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.doClose0(AbstractChannel.java:755)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:731)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.close(AbstractChannel.java:620)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.closeAll(NioEventLoop.java:772)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:995)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[err] com.ibm.srm.utils.cache.CacheException: Unable to connect to Redis server
[err]   at com.ibm.srm.utils.cache.impl.RedissonConnector.connect(RedissonConnector.java:122)
[err]   at com.ibm.srm.utils.cache.osgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:28)
[err]   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[err]   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[err]   at org.apache.aries.subsystem.core.internal.BasicSubsystem.start(BasicSubsystem.java:321)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.esa.internal.DeploySubsystemAction.access$000(DeploySubsystemAction.java:75)
[err]   at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.esa.internal.DeploySubsystemAction$2$1.run(DeploySubsystemAction.java:253)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[err] Caused by: org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: <server-host:server-port removed for security reasons>
[err]   at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool$1.lambda$run$0(ConnectionPool.java:159)
[err]   at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.lambda$onComplete$0(RedissonPromise.java:183)
[err]   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.lambda$createConnection$1(ConnectionPool.java:295)
[err]   at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.lambda$onComplete$0(RedissonPromise.java:183)
[err]   at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 1 more
[err] Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: <server-host:server-port removed for security reasons>
[err]   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   ... 8 more
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0017I: Web application removed (default_host): http://192.168.1.20:9080/srm/tsdqueries/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0022W: Application TSD has not started in 29.999 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [appSecurity-2.0, beanValidation-1.1, cdi-1.2, distributedMap-1.0, ejbLite-3.2, el-3.0, httpWhiteboard-1.0, jaxb-2.2, jaxrs-2.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, jdbc-4.1, jndi-1.0, jpa-2.1, jpaContainer-2.1, jsf-2.2, json-1.0, jsonp-1.0, jsp-2.3, localConnector-1.0, managedBeans-1.0, osgiBundle-1.0, servlet-3.1, ssl-1.0, webProfile-7.0, websocket-1.1].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The TS server started in 34.396 seconds.
TSD Query bundle stopped in 36.941 secs
TSD Query bundle initialized in 50.74 secs
Common-Utilities bundle stopped
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0402E: A bundle exception was generated when trying to install the application TSD into an OSGi framework.  The error text from the OSGi framework is: Exception in com.ibm.srm.utils.cache.osgi.Activator.start() of bundle Common-Utilities-Cache.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKN2001A: HTTP Whiteboard context root removed: http://192.168.1.20:9080/osgi/http/TSD
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0012I: The application TSD was not started.
```

I tried changing the "connectTimeout" property in the redis.properties file from 10000 to 20000 and it didn't work. Tried switching my networks also and still it did not work.

Edit: At times, I also get this error:

`Unable to init enough connections amount! Only 4 of 5 were initialized. Redis server: <server-host:server-port removed for security reasons>`

Comment: Are you able to connect to the redis server with other clients, like `redli` or `redis commander`?

Comment: I am a complete noob to redis. I installed redli on Mac using brew and tried this:

2022/08/01 09:47:44 Dial read tcp 192.168.1.20:61982->host:port: read: connection reset by peer

Comment: 192.168.x.x is a private network address, and not where a redis instance on the IBM Cloud would probably be found. Check the Overview page's Endpoints section of your instance in the IBM Cloud resource list to see how to properly connect to it.

Comment: I am trying from my local machine then it should be 192.168.x.x., right?

Comment: If you mean running the redis server on your local machine rather than in the IBM Cloud, yes, but that's not what your question says.